# Geometric Probability Distribution, Expected Values

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Question:

Let $X $~ Geometric $(\theta)$, and let $Y = \min(X, 100)$. Compute (a) $E(Y)$ and (b) $E(Y-X)$

I know that the Geometric distribution is $(1-\theta)^{k-1}\theta$ and I also know how to calculate expected value but I'm confused about what it means that $Y = \min(X,100)$?

Comment: It means that as samples from $X$ are realized, $Y$ takes the value of $X$ if it is smaller than $100$, and $Y$ takes the value of $100$ in all cases where $X$ takes the value $100$ or higher.

Comment: Note $Y-X$ takes negative values for $X >100$

Answer (score 1):

$$\forall\omega\in\Omega,\qquad Y(\omega)=\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}X(\omega)&\text{if}&X(\omega)\leqslant100\\ 100&\text{if}&X(\omega)\gt100\end{array}\right.$$
$$
E[Y]=100\,P[X\gt 100]+\sum_{k\leqslant100}k\,P[X=k]$$